# Where are the smart contract accounts stored in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, networkid

I have a single geth node running a private blockchain with a network ID `N` and data directory `data/`. I had deployed a smart contract `ContractName` on the same and things were working fine. I wanted to start fresh once again, so I deleted the directory `data/geth/` entirely and ran `geth init` and started my node with the same network ID `N`. However, when I enter `truffle console` and run `ContractName.address`, I am still returned an address. The block data has been reset and the new block number is 0. How is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason in the end. Turns out `truffle console` uses its own build files for contract addresses. So I had my previous compiled and deployed JSON files in the truffle build directory. Removing that directory showed my `ContractName` is not defined as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Keystore folder of the data directory stores information for the accounts. Delete following folders to remove the accounts information.

```
Mac:~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%\Ethereum
```

Comment: I'd done that. The contract was still shown.